# I want to show fileds and attributes in popup

Tags: android, arcgis

I want to show fileds and attributes in popup when I clicked a point. But I get Null Pointer Exception. Why I return to me null? Can you help please? How can I do? I did like esri android sample. but it doesnt work.

```
    /// long press to map
   mapView.setOnLongPressListener(new OnLongPressListener() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     // ArcGISFeatureLayer
        private ArcGISFeatureLayer featureLay = null;

      /// override onLongPress
        @Override
        public boolean onLongPress(final float v, final float v1) {
            if (mapView.isLoaded()) {
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()
                        && count.intValue() == 0)
                 //dismiss dialog
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                // Get the point featurelayer
                Layer[] layers = mapView.getLayers();
                for (Layer layer : layers) {
                    if (layer instanceof ArcGISFeatureLayer) {
                        ArcGISFeatureLayer fl = (ArcGISFeatureLayer) layer;
                        if (fl.getGeometryType() == Geometry.Type.POINT) {
                            featureLay = fl;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //// if featureLay null
                if (featureLay == null)
                    return false;

                ArcGISPopupInfo popupInfos = (ArcGISPopupInfo) featureLay.getPopupInfos();

              ///!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! return to me null////////////
                if (popupInfos == null)
                    return false;

                // Create a new feature
                Point point = mapView.toMapPoint(v, v1);
                Feature feature2;
                FeatureType[] types = featureLay.getTypes();
                if (types == null || types.length < 1) {
                    FeatureTemplate[] templates = featureLay
                            .getTemplates();
                    if (templates == null || templates.length < 1) {
                        feature2 = new Graphic(point, null);
                    } else {
                        feature2 = featureLay.createFeatureWithTemplate(
                                templates[0], point);
                    }
                } else {
                    feature2 = featureLay.createFeatureWithType(
                            featureLay.getTypes()[0], point);
                }

                // Instantiate a PopupContainer
                popupContainer = new PopupContainer(mapView);

                 // popup create 
                Popup popupp = featureLay.createPopup(mapView, 0, feature2);
                popupContainer.addPopup(popupp);
                popupp.setEditMode(true);
                createEditorBar(featureLay, false);

                // Create a dialog for the popups and display it.
                popupDialog = new PopupDialog(mapView.getContext(),
                        popupContainer);
              // show popup
                popupDialog.show();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace. At which line are you getting the null pointer exception?

Comment: ArcGISPopupInfo popupInfos = (ArcGISPopupInfo) featureLay.getPopupInfos();

Comment: and I get null these line: Popup popupp = featureLay.createPopup(mapView, 0, feature2);

Comment: can you please post the stacktrace?